# How to import python function from other folder?

Tags: python

I want to import function from `bot/main.py` into `bybitapi/server.py`. The structure of project looks like this:

[image]

So, in `server.py` I was trying to do it like this:

```py
from bot.main import notifyuserwithtriggeredalarms
```

But it doesn't work, it was about `bot package doesn't exists`. Also, I was trying to solve this using `os` and `sys`, I couldn't, so, how can I import function in `server.py` though other folder?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Comment: I saw this, actually, it doesn't.

Comment: Pretty sure it does answer your question. Do `sys.path.append('/path/to/project/directory')` and your imports will work. (That said, I don't think messing with `sys.path` is a nice and clean solution.)

Answer (score -2):

[mport a Module From the Parent Directory in Python by Adding It to PYTHONPATH](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/python-import-from-parent-directory/)

```
import os, sys

p = os.path.abspath('.')
sys.path.insert(1, p)

from main import notifyuserwithtriggeredalarms
```

Comment: This doesn't really do anything. You're adding the current working directory to `sys.path`, but 99% of the time (it depends on how you start python) it's already there. And even if it isn't, the CWD might not necessarily be set to the directory you need. Use something like `pathlib.Path(__file__).parent` to find the parent directory instead.